# Multivariable Function : Differentiability at a point and in a disc

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here's a problem my friend proposed.

A function $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following conditions.

1. At $(0,0)$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous.
2. There exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that in a disc $D_\epsilon (0,0)$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exists.

Does there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that in a disc $D_\epsilon (0,0)$, $f$ is differentiable?

We tried to use the definition of differentiability, (i. e. using increments) but to no avail. Is there a counterexample, or a valid proof? Thanks in advance.